# Drag and Drop jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have made one small thing using drag and drop jquery ui it works fine but it has only one issue.

In it i have one draggable div and one droppable area when draggable div drop on droppable area in it one div containing information generated this thing work properly but when too many div generated, they goes out of bound of droppable area and all div are generated horizontally, so how to deal with it?

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
#draggable_area

{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 250px;
    border : 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
#droppable_area
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border : 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 25%;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="droppable_area"></div>
<div id="draggable_area">
    <form id="f1">
    <br><br>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <input list="size" name="size1" placeholder="Size" style="max-width:80%" id="size1"> 

           <datalist id="size">
                <option value="200x200">
                <option value="200x600">
                <option value="300x300">
                <option value="300x600">
                <option value="300x900">
                <option value="400x400">
                <option value="600x600">
                <option value="600x1200">
                <option value="800x1200">
                <option value="1000x2000">
                <option value="200x300">
                <option value="250x375">
                <option value="300x450">
                <option value="300x750">
                <option value="300x1200">
                <option value="400x800">
                <option value="600x900">
                <option value="800x800">
                <option value="1000x1000">

            </datalist>
    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <input list="pc" name="pc1" placeholder="Product Category" style="max-width:80%" id="pc1"> 

           <datalist id="pc">
                <option value="Ceramic Wall">
                <option value="Ceramic/Semi-Porcelian Floor">
                <option value="SST/Vitrified Nano">
                <option value="Double charge/Multi charge Nano(DC)">
                <option value="Vetrified Glazed Tile(GVT)">
                <option value="Polished Glazed Vetrified Nano(PGVT)">
                <option value="Color Body">
                <option value="Stone/Kota Marble & granites">
                <option value="Combo Plan">
                <option value="Slim Tile">
                <option value="Raw Material">

            </datalist>
    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;         
    <input list="ff" name="ff1" placeholder="Feel/Finish" style="max-width:80%" id="ff1"> 

            <datalist id="ff">
                    <option value="Glossy">
                    <option value="Special Protection Coat">
                    <option value="Matt/Suede/Honed">
                    <option value="Polished Glossy">
                    <option value="Rustic/Rough Surface">
                    <option value="Luster">
                    <option value="Metallic">
                    <option value="Glazed Polish Nano / Half Polished">
                    <option value="Lapato/ Sugar /Leather">

                </datalist>
     <br>  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;         

     <input list="q1" name="q11" placeholder="Quality" style="max-width:80%" id="q11"> 

               <datalist id="q1">
                    <option value="Premium">
                    <option value="Standard">
                    <option value="Other">

                </datalist> 
    </form>               

</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i= 1;
    var a;
    $('#draggable_area').draggable({
        revert: true,
        stop: function () {
            document.getElementById('f1').reset();
                    }
    });
    $('#droppable_area').droppable({
        accept: '#draggable_area',
        drop: function()
        {
            var size = document.getElementById('size1').value;
            var product_Quality = document.getElementById('pc1').value;
            var feel_finish = document.getElementById('ff1').value;
            var quality = document.getElementById('q11').value;

            console.log(size+" "+product_Quality+" "+feel_finish+" "+quality);

            var label1 = document.createElement('label');
            var label2 = document.createElement('label');
            var label3 = document.createElement('label');
            var label4 = document.createElement('label');

            var text1 = document.createTextNode(size);
            var text2 = document.createTextNode(product_Quality);
            var text3 = document.createTextNode(feel_finish);
            var text4 = document.createTextNode(quality);

            label1.appendChild(text1);
            label2.appendChild(text2);
            label3.appendChild(text3);
            label4.appendChild(text4);



            var div = document.createElement('div');
            //div.textContent = "Sup, y'all?";
            div.setAttribute('class', 'note'+ i );
            div.setAttribute('id','n'+i);
            var b  = 'n'+ i ;
            console.log(b)
            document.getElementById('droppable_area').appendChild(div);
            $('div').draggable({
                start: function()
                {
                     a = this.id;
                    console.log(a);
                }
            });

            document.getElementById(b).appendChild(label1);
            document.getElementById(b).appendChild(label2);
            document.getElementById(b).appendChild(label3);
            document.getElementById(b).appendChild(label4);


            document.getElementById(b).style.width = '100px';
            document.getElementById(b).style.height = '100px';
            document.getElementById(b).style.boxShadow = '10px 10px 10px grey';
            document.getElementById(b).style.border = '3px solid black';
            i++;
        }   
    });
</script>
```

Please help me with this.
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: sure. @DimalChandrasiri

Comment: jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/spLcaykh/1/  @DimalChandrasiri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the elements inside the container, you could add the following code to the end of the styling section. This would line all the new elements horizontally and will get stacked.

```
document.getElementById(b).style.float = 'left';
```

The following is the updated jsfiddle.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spLcaykh/2/)

If you want to restrict adding after the container is full, you would need to write a separate logic to identify that.

To make the droppable area to have a scroll bar just add `overflow:auto` to the style of that container.

```
#droppable_area{
    //rest of the css
    overflow:auto;
}
```

This would add a vertical scrollbar as soon as the content exceeds the container.

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spLcaykh/4/)

Comment: If container is full, then i need to start scrolling of it, how to start it? @DimalChandrasiri

Comment: But here we are not able drag out small div that is generated...this problem occurs. we also need solve this. @DimalChandrasiri

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider adding float to your little boxes?

If you add float to your element, they will start filling your dragged area.

```
document.getElementById(b).style.float = 'left';
```

To make content scroll after;

```
#droppable_area{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

To remove the item from the container, you should add this little code to creation of the little boxes. So that when you try to move it from the box, it will remove itself.

```
$('div').draggable({
    start: function () {
        a = this.id;
        console.log(a);
    },
    stop: function () {
        if (parseInt($(this).css('top')) < 0 || parseInt($(this).css('left')) < 0) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If container is full, then i need to start scrolling of it, how to start it? @DemeterDimitri

Comment: You can add overflow css to the container item.

Comment: But then we are not able drag out that small item out of that division @DemeterDimitri

Comment: I edited my answer for you to remove the small item out.